# How to improve a ERD

Tags: database, erd

This question is based on my plan at [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168701/to-make-a-plan-for-my-first-mysql-project).

My entity-relationship diagram is

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/sequence-diagram.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/sequence-diagram.png)

I would like to know the following.

**Does my sequence diagram match the following relation diagram?**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/table-problem-3.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/table-problem-3.png)

Comment: That is a modified form of an ERD, not a sequence diagram.

Comment: Or a class diagram... Yours seem to be in between, but it's definitely not a sequence diagram.

Comment: The diagrams read to me as the first one being the Logical model, and the second is the Physical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the first diagram as the Logical model, typically the tables defined in the Logical also exist in the physical - you're missing the QUESTION-TAGS (nee QUESTION-SUBJECTS) table.  You have a one-to-one relationship between QUESTION and MONITOR-CHECK, which means there's no value to having MONITOR-CHECK - move the attributes into the QUESTION
table.

Viewing the second diagram as the Physical ERD model - there's no benefit to having two tables with a one-to-one relationship.  I'm speaking about the QUESTION / QUESTION-BODY, and QUESTION / MODERATOR-CHECK tables.

QUESTION-SUBJECTS is poorly named - if by your note the record represents a "tag", then name the table accordingly.  This table would be a code table (having CODE, DESCRIPTION columns) because you want to keep the values consistent for queries to perform well.  That said, you need an xref/lookup/corollary table between the QUESTION and QUESTION-TAGS table in order to have a one [question related] to many [question tags].

QUESTION-TAG-XREF

- QUESTION-ID (pk)
- QUESTION-TAG-CODE (pk)

Comment: Please, see my reply to your question above. Do you mean that?

Comment: Please, see my comment to your comment below.

Comment: I opened the following thread based on your answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185626/why-does-many-to-many-data-structure-require-two-additional-tables

Answer (score 1):

This is my reply to *rexem*'s answer.

I understand your answer as follows:

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db-problem-2.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db-problem-2.png)

and the second diagram as

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db-problem-1.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db-problem-1.png)

I left the xref table for the question-body because I may need to store the changes to my questions too in the future.

Comment: Both lack the QUESTION-TAGS table.  Table names don't change between logical and physical models - QUESTION-HISTORY-XREF and QUESTION-BODY should actually be QUESTION-HISTORY.  If you think you need the QUESTION-HISTORY as an audit table, then keep it.


I marked you back up to 0 cuz stackoverflow doesn't allow for back & forth conversation.

Comment: `Both lack the QUESTION-TAGS table.` @ Do you mean that to add a new "help-table" between `Question-Tag-xref` and `Question`?

Comment: No.  I don't recognize the help-table as representing an actual table, just a note on the model.  You need to add QUESTION-TAGS as a table to both models, attached to the QUESTION-TAG-XREF table.

Answer (score 0):

The first diagram looks a bit more like a class diagram.