# Anyone knows a good hack to make django-registration use emails as usernames?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am planning to do email-registration-activation on my site which will be launched very soon. I have just started looking at django-registration and I am open to other email-registration-activation system available on django.

My only requirement is that for my site, I don't actually use usernames. Rather, user logs in with their emails and passwords. I want to get an expert's opinion how to modify django-registration *cleanly* and *safely* for this purpose.

If there are easier solutions which are scalable, feel free to post up here.

Answer (score 6):

We used `django-registration` with a custom backend, where we overwrote (or defined) the `clean` method of the registration form:

```
def clean(self):
    ...
    # use the email as the username 
    if 'email' in self.cleaned_data:
        self.cleaned_data['username'] = self.cleaned_data['email']
```

There are other ways:

- http://bitbucket.org/hakanw/django-email-usernames/wiki/Home
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/74/
- http://www.davidcramer.net/code/224/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django.html

Note that by default, usernames can be only **30 chars** long. You'll need a hack for that, too:

- [Can django's auth_user.username be varchar(75)? How could that be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610088/can-djangos-auth-user-username-be-varchar75-how-could-that-be-done)

Comment: One minor nit, I think it should be "def clean(self):"

Answer (score 0):

Since `Django 1.5` now it possible to have custom **auth.User** and make *email* address as *username*.