# Which is the easiest way to remove Django User model's 30 character limit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can django's auth_user.username be varchar(75)? How could that be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610088/can-djangos-auth-user-username-be-varchar75-how-could-that-be-done)

I've inherited a Django application which uses a custom form-less auth backend. It works around the 30 character limit in `django.contrib.auth.models.User` by a SQL hack `ALTER TABLE auth_user MODIFY COLUMN username varchar(90);`, which is of course only valid for the database, but not for forms. Since I'm trying to remove all the hacks from code including SQL ones, I'm looking for a proper way to remove that limitation. How would you recommend removing it?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610088/can-djangos-auth-user-username-be-varchar75-how-could-that-be-done. See the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any clean way to make such a change to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model. In fact almost any change is tricky.

One very flaky way would be to delegate the username to an `UserProfile` model. You can define an `UserProfile` model that has a one-to-one relationship with `User`. You'll then have to add a field to the profile model to hold the longer-than-usual username.

It doesn't end there. To make things seamless you'll have to write custom managers to make sure that the username from the profile field is used when querying for users.

Now that I have spelled it out I don't like the above method at all. Needless to say it is untested.