# How big can I make email, first_name, last_name and username in auth.User?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I've lost an user today :(

An user tried to signup to my site and his email was bigger than `75 characters` (Django's `auth.User` default), I'm working on a migration to fix that, but I wonder, how big can I make the column without having to worry about `performance|storage|memory` issues?

I use `PostgreSQL` and `Django 1.3.1` on `Heroku`.

Here's the `South` migration I intend to run:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Changing User.username, User.email, User.first_name and User.last_name
        # to bigger fields
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'username', models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'email', models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'first_name', models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'last_name', models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True))

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'username', models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'email', models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'first_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True))
        db.alter_column('auth_user', 'last_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can django's auth\_user.username be varchar(75)? How could that be done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610088/can-djangos-auth-user-username-be-varchar75-how-could-that-be-done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only migrations will leave problems associated with form validation, django.contrib.admin and etc.

There is very similar question you can see here: [Can django's auth_user.username be varchar(75)? How could that be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610088/can-djangos-auth-user-username-be-varchar75-how-could-that-be-done)

There's also package than you can use to extend username field: https://github.com/GoodCloud/django-longer-username (based on that question)

You can extend that code found in that package to extend email field too (since it extends only username field)