# How do I retrieve and stores these guids for later use?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have a table `Partners` generated by

```
CREATE TABLE Partners ( 
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, -- 254 is optimal length according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199190/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-an-email-address-in-a-database
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and a attempt at a sproc for inserting a row and retrieving the `id` of the inserted row:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPartner 
     @name NVARCHAR(50), @email NVARCHAR(254)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    INSERT INTO Partners (name,email)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @new_guid
    VALUES (@name,@email)   
    SELECT @new_guid
END
```

Suppose I want to (1) call `AddPartner` with `(name,email)` equal `('some dude','dude192@gmail.com`) and return the `id` (call it `dude_id`) so that I can later (2) use it when I insert another row:

```
INSERT INTO Answers (question_id,partner_id,val) VALUES (1,dude_id,24);
```

How exactly can I do that? And will having `GO` statements between (1) and (2) ruin everything?

Comment: If you do not have the ID at the time of import check out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648/best-way-to-get-identity-of-inserted-row

Answer (score 0):

Add `Output Parameter` to your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Addpartner (@name     NVARCHAR(50),
                             @email    NVARCHAR(254),
                             @new_guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER output)
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      INSERT INTO Partners
                  (name,email)
      OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @new_guid
      VALUES      (@name,@email)
  END 


DECLARE @new_guid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 

EXEC Addpartner 'some dude', 'dude192@gmail.com', @new_guid  output

INSERT INTO Answers
            (question_id,partner_id,val)
VALUES      (@output_identity,'dude_id',24);
```

Comment: The `id` is a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, not an `INT`

Comment: @user5648283 - check now

Comment: I'm getting the error `Must declare the table variable "@new_guid".` on the `OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @new_guid` line