# Into what C# data type should I retrieve a SQL Server UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE Partners 
(
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
    name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email NVARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, -- 254 is optimal length according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199190/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-an-email-address-in-a-database
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPartnersWithIds
AS
    SELECT id, name 
    FROM Partners;
```

The result of which I'm trying to reading into a `List<PartnerWithId>` where `PartnerWithId` is defined by

```
public class PartnerWithId
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My method for doing so is

```
    public List<PartnerWithId> GetPartners ( )
    {
        List<PartnerWithId> Partners = new List<PartnerWithId>();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPartnersWithIds", this._Conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            this._Conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Partners.Add(new PartnerWithId {
                        Id = (Guid)dataReader.GetString(0),
                        Name = dataReader.GetString(1)
                    });
                }
            }
            this._Conn.Close();
        }
        return Partners;
    }
```

but I'm getting an error

> Cannot convert type `string` to `System.Guid`

on chunk `(Guid)dataReader.GetString(0)` (which was really just a guess). What is the correct way to get this value?

Comment: You are getting that error since you are using the `GetString()` method of the `DataReader` class. you should use `GetGuid()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *cast* try creating `Guid` with Guid string or use `Guid.Parse`

```
 Id = new Guid(dataReader.GetString(0)),
```

or better to use `DataReader.GetGuid()` directly instead of getting string and converting into Guid.

```
 Id = dataReader.GetGuid(0),
```