# Sql Table data type for email address?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

What data type should I use for an email? Just started to learn SQL, and I tried to make some columns, here's table for ID, Username, Password, Money, and Email.

Did I make that correctly?

[image]

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server here, which are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the image

Comment: Does the email contain only text?

Comment: no it contains the @ symbol, so what type i should use?>

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199190/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-an-email-address-in-a-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the optimal length for an email address in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199190/what-is-the-optimal-length-for-an-email-address-in-a-database)

Comment: I suggest against the use of `money`. use `decimal`. `money` can and does have rounding issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's good to go with **NVARCHAR(320) - 64** characters for local part **+ @ + 255** for domain name.

You Use **varchar(255)** and **nvarchar(255)** Data type

Answer (score 8):

Since the max lenght for a email is 254 characters, i would recommend you to use nvarchar(255). That should be enough

Answer (score 4):

you can use varchar as your data type for email column as emails are usually composed of letters, numbers and special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The right value of data lenght for the email field is database-agnostic. If you are also considering standard SQL types, the same can be said for data type, that is a string.
You can take a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37014/in-what-data-type-should-i-store-an-email-address-in-database).