# What is the difference between CHARACTER VARYING and VARCHAR in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, varchar, varying

[John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196873/to-prevent-the-use-of-duplicate-tags-in-a-database/1197192#1197192) uses `CHARACTER VARYING` in the places where I use `VARCHAR`.
I am a beginner, while he is an expert.
This suggests me that there is something which I do not know.

**What is the difference between CHARACTER VARYING and VARCHAR in PostgreSQL?**

Comment: the real question should be what is the difference with type TEXT. But perhaps back then in 2009 this type was not yet around

Answer (score 202, accepted):

`VARCHAR` is an alias for `CHARACTER VARYING`, so no difference, see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) :)

> The notations `varchar(n)` and `char(n)` are aliases for `character varying(n)` and `character(n)`, respectively. `character` without length specifier is equivalent to `character(1)`. If `character varying` is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size. The latter is a PostgreSQL extension.

Note on capitalization: The PostgreSQL documentation uses the all lower case stylization: `character varying`. In contrast the official SQL standard uses the stylization with all caps throughout its 1000 pages: `CHARACTER VARYING`.

Comment: It's the other way round: varchar is an alias for varying. Not to be pedantic, but it's right there in your quote.

Comment: @zerzevul One might disagree with the documentation and agree with Charles here, given that `varchar(n)`, etc. are the ANSI standards and this syntax is peculiar to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 25):

The [PostgreSQL documentation on Character Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) is a good reference for this. They are two different names for the same type.

Answer (score 15):

**The short answer:** there is no difference.

**The long answer:** `CHARACTER VARYING` is the official type name from the ANSI SQL standard, which all compliant databases are required to support. (SQL compliance Feature ID [E021-02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance#:%7E:text=Yes-,E021%2D02,-CHARACTER%20VARYING%20data).)

`VARCHAR` is a shorter alias which all modern databases also support. I prefer `VARCHAR` because it's shorter and because the longer name feels pedantic. However, postgres tools like `pg_dump` and `\d` will output `character varying`.

Answer (score 7):

The only difference is that `CHARACTER VARYING` is more human friendly than `VARCHAR`

Comment: @joop I haven't had the privilege of being exposed to COBOL but I have been exposed to English and i think "VARCH ARe what?" :-)

Comment: Beside I think it is confusing top programmers ;) They are used to varchar

Answer (score 3):

Both are the same thing but many of the databases are not providing the varying char mainly postgreSQL is providing. So for the multi database like Oracle Postgre and DB2 it is good to use the Varchar