# To SHA512-hash a password in MySQL database by Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, hash

This question is based [on the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182798/to-improve-a-relation-figure-for-a-database/1182807#1182807).

I would like to know how you can hash your password by SHA1 and then remove the clear-text password in a MySQL database by Python.

**How can you hash your password in a MySQL database by Python?**

Comment: Don't use SHA1 if you don't have to. SHA2-256 or SHA2-512 are much more secure options, and if this is a new application there is no backwards compatibility requirement to use SHA1.

Comment: For passwords, SHA1 might even be overkill. A good salt and MD5 is plenty strong enough for most applications.

Comment: Why risk it? It's an entirely trivial change to use a better hash algorithm. (You just change `hashlib.md5` to `hashlib.sha512`!) MD5 is dead, and anyone who doesn't know that shouldn't go anywhere near passwords.

Comment: fixed title - thanks for comments!

Comment: Listen to kquinn, not Thomas Owens. There's no reason to use low grade options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the documentation says you should use [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) library not the sha since python 2.5.

It is pretty easy to do make a hash.

```
hexhash = hashlib.sha512("some text").hexdigest()
```

This hex number will be easy to store in a database.

Comment: Better to do `hexhash = hashlib.sha512("some text" + salt).hexdigest()`, where `salt` is a random string generated for each password and stored in the DB along with the hash. It helps avoid rainbow table attacks.

Answer (score 7):

If you're storing passwords in a database, a recommended article to read is Jeff's [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html). This article describes the use of *salt* and some of the things about storing passwords that are deceptively easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/sha.html

The python documentation explains this a lot better than I can.

Comment: It's depreciated since Python 2.5, you should now use http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib (Although, I'm sure this answer was valid when it was posted in 2009).

Answer (score 1):

You don't remove the clear-text password when you hash the password. What you do is accept an input from the user, hash the input, and compare the hash of the input to the hash stored in the database. You should never store or send the plain-text password that the user has.

That said, you can use the sha library [as scrager said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183161/to-sha1-hash-a-password-in-mysql-database-by-python/1183173#1183173) (pre-Python 2.5) and the hashlib library [as David Raznick said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183161/to-sha1-hash-a-password-in-mysql-database-by-python/1183213#1183213) in newer versions of Python.