# Python's safest method to store and retrieve passwords from a database

Tags: python, encryption, passwords, password-protection

Looking to store usernames and passwords in a database, and am wondering what the safest way to do so is.  I know I have to use a salt somewhere, but am not sure how to generate it securely or how to apply it to encrypt the password.  Some sample Python code would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Lots of info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183161/to-sha512-hash-a-password-in-mysql-database-by-python

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Store the password+salt as a hash and the salt. Take a look at how Django does it: [basic docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/) and [source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/models.py).
In the db they store  `<type of hash>$<salt>$<hash>` in a single char field. You can also store the three parts in separate fields.

The function to set the password:

```
def set_password(self, raw_password):
    import random
    algo = 'sha1'
    salt = get_hexdigest(algo, str(random.random()), str(random.random()))[:5]
    hsh = get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password)
    self.password = '%s$%s$%s' % (algo, salt, hsh)
```

The get_hexdigest is just a thin wrapper around some hashing algorithms. You can use hashlib for that. Something like `hashlib.sha1('%s%s' % (salt, hash)).hexdigest()`

And the function to check the password:

```
def check_password(raw_password, enc_password):
    """
    Returns a boolean of whether the raw_password was correct. Handles
    encryption formats behind the scenes.
    """
    algo, salt, hsh = enc_password.split('$')
    return hsh == get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password)
```

Comment: Could be better - you don't use a constant time string compare (not so important here, but if the user does the hashing, for example secure cookies, then you must use constant time string compare), and sha1 can be brute forced for predictable (i.e. most people's) passwords.

Comment: These functions are class functions, but the OP did not ask for class functions.

Comment: Note that the code in this answer uses random.random  as source for the salts which is considered insecure for security related purposes according to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html . Additionally it uses a single round of sha1 which is insecure for password hashing, and according to the Django documentation Django doesn't do that anymore by default. As mentioned in my answer it is better to use the PBKDF2 
 functionality from https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation . PBKDF2 is also the default algorithm used by Django at the moment.

Answer (score 16):

I think it is best to use a function dedicated to hashing passwords for this. I explain some reasons for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10948614/893857
Nowadays the standard library has a [dedicated section in the documentation for hashing password](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation). It even mentions that you should get your salt from a cryptographically secure random source like `os.urandom()`.

Comment: Thank you!  passlib - quick and easy. :-)

Answer (score 15):

I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18488878/1661689, and so did @Koffie.

I don't know how to emphasize enough that the accepted answer is NOT secure. It is better than plain text, and better than an unsalted hash, but it is still **extremely vulnerable** to dictionary and even brute-force attacks. Instead, please **use a SLOW KDF** like bcrypt (or *at least* PBKDF2 with 10,000 iterations)

Comment: Are you suggesting that storing correctly salted, hashed passwords is an **extremely vulnerable** practice? You can't use a dictionary attack on salted hashes.

Comment: No. I am suggesting that a single iteration of SHA-1, as the code above suggests, is not "correctly salted and hashed".  You *can* use a dictionary attack on salted hashes, and the faster the hash, the faster each pw can be tried. Would you rather it took one day or 64,000 days for the attack to succeed? SHA-x hashing is *very* fast on custom hardware (ASICs). https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Impose_infeasible_verification_on_attacker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545677/python-passlib-what-is-the-best-value-for-rounds

Comment: @rz says "take a look at how Django does it" and then shows code that is completely different. Django *does* do it correctly: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L216

Answer (score 3):

If you have enough control over both endpoints of the application, the absolute best way is using [PAK-Z+](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/passwdPK/contributions.html).

(Edited: the original version recommended [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) but PAK-Z+ has a proof of security.)

Answer (score 3):

For flask application or any python application you can use the werkzeug WSGI web application library, which provides you the option to generate and decode the password with salt and different types of algorithms in a format like this : method$salt$hash

The default salt length is 16 and algo used is sha256

Eg.

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

raw_pwd = 'mySecurePassword'

# genreates the encrypted password
hashed_pwd = generate_password_hash(raw_pwd)

# to verify the password
print(check_password_hash(hashed_pwd, raw_pwd)) # return boolean value after validating password
```

you can read more about werkzeug security here : https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#module-werkzeug.security

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way (taken from effbot), provided passwords with a length greater than 8 will not be a problem*:

```
import crypt

import random, string

def getsalt(chars = string.letters + string.digits):
    # generate a random 2-character 'salt'
    return random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars)
```

for generate the password :

```
crypt.crypt("password", getsalt())
```

*: A password with a length greater than 8 is stripped from the right down to 8 chars long

Comment: crypt have problems to encrypt password of more than 8 chars I think