# pbkdf2 VS bcrypt, rounds?

Tags: python, bcrypt, pbkdf2

I've a dumb question (and probably has been already asked):

People always compare between **BCrypt** and **PBKDF2** and say that **BCrypt** is better because it is for example slower to use **GPU**, but they ignore the `Rounds value`, espetially when i talk about **Python**, where **BCrypt** is not powerful, so my question is simple:

[The tests used the excellent **python** library **Passlib**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib)

is it worth to use **BCrypt** even with small round value? in Passlib, the default value is `12`, tested and gave me `0.40 seconds`,  while **PBKDF2** gave me with the default value which is `12000` rounds: `0.142 seconds`

so for example, if i use BCrypt with only 5 rounds, i'll say: hey, my application is more secure -and faster- than using PBKDF2 with 12000 rounds! (it seems dumb i know, sorry).

[here is the benchmark results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545677/python-passlib-what-is-the-best-value-for-rounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the actual number of iterations in bcrypt is 2^rounds, so for example rounds=5 -> iterations=32, and the default rounds=12 -> iterations=4096.  When comparing between bcrypt and pbkdf2, make sure that they mean the same thing when they say "rounds".

General rule on bcrypt is to use the largest value for rounds that you can afford, in terms of user logon not being annoyingly slow.  Your test of 0.4 seconds sounds like you have it about right.

Comment: from what i've found, it seems developpers follow current year: multiple of 1000 `(12*1000)` for 2012, and `2^12` for  bcrypt