# What is the most effective method of storing and recalling data?

Tags: python, database, import, export

I've been wanting to build a pretty big project which pretty much mimics Twitter, I've just started it and have run into a little error with account creation. I was wondering what the best method of storing and recalling data is. I'm well aware I can use .txt files to do this, but then I've found it's trickier to make the program recognize the structure of the data.

```
For example, the file might look like this:
acnt - twigman
pass - yellow
```

And the user creating an account might use the same name, and I would need to stop that, but I wouldn't know how to make the program know where the username starts and ends.

If I could use a database within the Python program, that would be a heck of a lot easier, it would mean the program can run as just one file and it would be easier to code. The program could also recognize the beginning and end of a user name without needing to write more script for it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using a database is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectations of Python are very low. That is great news because you are going to be very happy.

You can definitely use a database with Python. The simplest and quickest to set up as well as closest to what you described is a file database: SQLite. [Here](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/) is a great tutorial to start.

If you want to stick to simpler than than, you can use the [pickle module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) or the [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) to ‘persist’ your data

Of course, once your database increases significantly in size, you can move on to MySQL or PostgreSQL or others.

I encourage you to check out database abstraction tools such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) as they can make your life easier.

If you are building a web application, then why reinvent the wheel? Choose one from the [many Python web frameworks](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). Some if not all of them abstract away the database so you can focus on your application and its features.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a database is really the way to go here. This gets deep pretty fast, but as far as handling the python sytax it's fairly straightforward. This answer handles that subject well:

[How do I connect to a MySQL Database in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372885/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-python)

If you are truly going to be interacting with real users, you should learn about how to properly secure their passwords via hashing or other methods. **Storing passwords in plain text is a big no-no.** Here's an interesting place to start for password hashing in Python:

[Python's safest method to store and retrieve passwords from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572099/pythons-safest-method-to-store-and-retrieve-passwords-from-a-database)

Comment: Thanks for this, the txt file was a demo, of course, I'll be modifying it for actual potential use once I'm happy with the program itself!

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite or any other RDBMS like PostgreSQL.
To use Python with RDBMS: 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces