# Python mysql - the login validation reads the encryped password and not the actuall one

Tags: python, mysql, authentication

I'm trying to write a login page using mysql and python for my degree but I couldn't figure out why the login validation reads the encrypted hashlib password instead of the actuall password

I couldn't figure out why the login validation reads the encrypted hashlib password instead of the actuall password.

**This is function of the signup which encryptes it in the Database:
**

```
def connect_database():
l, u, s, d = 0, 0, 0, 0
capitalalphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
smallalphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
specialchar = "!@#$%^&\*()"
digits = "0123456789"
forbidden_words = \['qwerty', 'password', 'zxcvbnm'\]  # List of forbidden words in passwords
badwords = 0  # Check if there are forbidden words in passwords
if emailEntry.get() == '' or usernameEntry.get() == '' or passwordEntry.get() == '' or confirmpasswordEntry.get() == '':
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All fields are required!')
elif passwordEntry.get() != confirmpasswordEntry.get():
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Password does not match!')
elif check.get() == 0:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Please agree to all terms and conditions')
else:
try:
connect = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="somepassword123")
cursor = connect.cursor()
except:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Database Connectivity Issue')
return
try:  # This function creates the db. if the db already exists, it won't run again
query = 'create database users'
cursor.execute(query)
query = 'use users'
cursor.execute(query)
query = 'create table userdata(id int auto_increment primary key not null, email varchar(50), username varchar(50), password longtext(500))'
cursor.execute(query)
except:
password = passwordEntry.get()
for i in password:
if i in digits:
d += 1
if i in smallalphabets:
l += 1
if i in capitalalphabets:
u += 1
if i in specialchar:
s += 1
for word in forbidden_words:
if word in passwordEntry.get():
badwords += 1
if l \>= 1 and u \>= 1 and s \>= 1 and d \>= 1 and l + s + u + d == len(password) and len(
password) \>= 10 and badwords == 0:
salt = "1qz"  # Inserting a permanent salt
salt = salt.encode('utf-8')  # Encodes salt
password_and_salt = password.encode('utf-8') + salt  # Adding salt to the password
password_hash = hashlib.sha256(password_and_salt).hexdigest()  # Hash the password
cursor.execute('use users')
query = 'insert into userdata(email, username, password) values(%s, %s, %s)'  # Puts the data inside the table
cursor.execute(query, (emailEntry.get(), usernameEntry.get(), password_hash))
connect.commit()  # Commit all changes
connect.close()
cursor.close()
messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Your account has been successfully created')
clear()
signup_window.destroy()  # Closes the register page once the account has been created
import signin
else:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Password is not valid')
```

**and this one is the login page which takes the encrypted hashed code from the db and not the password:**

```
def login_user():
attempts = 0  # Failed login attempts
max_attempts = 1  # Maximum number of failed login attempts
while attempts \< max_attempts:
if UsernameEntry.get() == '' or PasswordEntry.get() == '':
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'All fields are required!')
else:
try:
connect = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="somepassword123")
cursor = connect.cursor()
except:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Connection is not established, try again')
return
query = 'use users'
cursor.execute(query)
query = 'select \* from userdata where username=%s and password=%s'
cursor.execute(query, (UsernameEntry.get(), PasswordEntry.get()))
check = cursor.fetchone()
if check is not None:  # Correct username and password
messagebox.showinfo('Welcome', 'Log In Successful')
else:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Invalid username or password')
attempts += 1
if attempts == max_attempts:
messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Too many failed login attempts \[3\]')
```

any help will be apprieitated thank you very much!

Comment: I think that this answer is what you are looking for: <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572099/pythons-safest-method-to-store-and-retrieve-passwords-from-a-database

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: Can you point me to where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You insert a hashed password into the database (which is fine). Then in the `SELECT` query you use the raw value of password, but the database contains only the hashed version. Your database doesn't know the raw value (again, which is fine).

In the login_user method, you should hash the password value before using it in the SQL query. If you query the database with the hashed password then you should get the correct results.