# To get primary and foreign keys right in ERD

Tags: database, primary-key, key, foreign-keys, erd

I read my notes and I am now unsure about the keys.

**My logical diagram**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-11.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-11.png)

This table should be in line with the following physical ERD

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-22.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db-22.png)

I have only one foreign key in the table `Question`.

I would like to know

- should the `question-id` and `question-tag` in the table *Question-tag-xref*, AND `question-id` and `answer` in the table *Answers* be also foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masi - Logical models don't usually contain data type (string, int, etc) information, but do indicate if the attribute (becomes a column in the Physical model) is optional (able to be null or not).

That said, yes - the QUESTION-ID and QUESTION-TAG columns would be foreign keys in the QUESTION-TAG-XREF table.  Here's a physical view of QUESTION-TAG-XREF:

**QUESTION-TAGS-XREF**

- QUESTION-ID (pk, fk relationship with QUESTIONS table)
- QUESTION-TAG-CODE (pk, fk relationship with QUESTION-TAG table)

Both columns are the pk to ensure you can't have duplicate tags for a given question.

You are correct that QUESTION-ID would be a foreign key in the ANSWERS table, in reference to the QUESTION table.

Comment: What is `QUESTION-TAG-CODE`? --- Do you meant we should have an extra table for question-tags?

Comment: Yes.  QUESTION-TAG-XREF only contains foreign keys; you need a table to contain the QUESTION-TAG codefied values.

Comment: I updated my pictures to indicate how I understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both ERDs, here are the foreign keys I would want to 
put in place:

First ERD:
Question-Tag-xref(question-id) should refer to Question(question-id).
Answers(question-id) should refer to Question(question-id).
Question(user-id) should refer to User(user-id).

Second ERD:
Question-Tag-xref(question-id) should refer to Question(question-id).
Answers(question-id) should refer to Question(question-id).
Question(user-id) should refer to user-info(user-id).

I get only one foreign key in the Question table too.

In answer to your question:
The column question-id in Question-tag-xref should  have a foreign key reference to Question(question-id).
The column question-id in the answers table should have a foreign key reference to Question(question-id)

K

Comment: Please, see my edit of my question. I updated the pictures to show you how I understand your answer.

Comment: Logical and Physical ERD models represent the same model - there's only one ERD to comment on here.  Logical ERDs don't contain data type information, but do indicate if a table attribute is optional (able to be null or not).  Attributes in a Logical model get converted into table columns in the Physical, but it isn't always a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: @rexem: Could you give an example where I should add `null` or `not`?