# Making cgi.FieldStorage Store User Inputs?

Tags: python, session, cgi

I wrote a simple Python CGI script but it has a bug :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import cgi,sys,random

sys.stderr = sys.stdout

num1 = random.randrange(1,11)
num2 = random.randrange(1,11)
answer = num1 + num2

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("<code>%d + %d :</code>") % (num1,num2)
print("""
<form method=POST action="">
<hr>
<th align=right>
<code><b>Answer:</b></code>
<input type=text name="answer">
<tr>""")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

try:
    if form["answer"].value == str(answer):
        print "<br><b>Good</b>"
    else:
        print "<br><b>Wrong</b>"

except KeyError:
    pass
```

The numbers regenerates each time this code executes and it can't compare the user input to the answer becouse cgi.FieldStorage does not store that input:

[image]

PHP programmers use " session_start() " to do what I want to do :

```
<?php
//Start the session so we can store what the code actually is.
session_start();
$text = rand(1,11);
$_SESSION["answer"] = $answer;
.......
?>
```

What about Python ? How can we do it?

Edit : I'm really not sure if it is sessions or not .. what I just need is a way to keep what user has inputed so I can compare his answer with the correct answer

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185406/how-do-i-start-a-session-in-a-python-web-application

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. One is [beaker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Beaker). It's a WSGI middleware designed to do caching and session storage. Not sure how it integrates with a regular CGI app, but shouldn't be too difficult. This would close to PHP's `session_start()` and storing things in `$_SESSION`. Beaker has a number of ways to store session information (cookie with session data, cooking with session id, etc etc)

The other way I can think of would be to have a hidden `<input>` element with the original numbers. This would be submitted with the form, and available in `form`. To be honest, this is a bad way to do things. It's open to a user attack and therefore is not secure. I know this is just a test application, but might as well start off on the right foot :)