# What is the best method to set a session cookie using Python 3.x and Cgi on Apache?

Tags: apache, python-3.x, cgi, session-cookies

I develop in Php, Perl and now am liking Python so much that I want to use it on the web.  I can get things working that I need except for a good method for setting/managing sessions.  Any help out there?  Point me to a library? or ideally post some working python code for my technology stack?
(looking for updated information on how to do this without depending on any framework)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start a session in a Python web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185406/how-do-i-start-a-session-in-a-python-web-application)

Comment: Very very very similar.  But I don't want to use frameworks as I stated.  I am checking if I can get the Beaker comment to work from the other post.

Comment: If you are familiar with the code syntax to send a simple session, get that session number and delete one to create a new one.  That is what I am trying to get to.  Please post it if you have done it with Beaker or something like it.

Comment: Dogpile may also be a solution.  Currently I have not gotten Dogpile or Beaker to work but I have not spent much time on it.  More time available tonight.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185406/how-do-i-start-a-session-in-a-python-web-application/45362757#45362757  Find the answer here.