# To improve SQL-queries in DDL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ddl

**Improvements done**

1. nvarchar(5000) -> nvarchar(4000) BUT no nvarchar in PostgreSQL => TEXT
2. memory limits to some variables
3. the syntax slightly changed to more readable
4. dashes to underscores
5. [Magnus' improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195816/to-improve-sql-queries-in-ddl/1198220#1198220)

I am following [my plan for my first database project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168701/to-make-a-plan-for-my-first-mysql-project).

I would like to know any weaknesses in the queries and in the relational table.

**SQL-queries in DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE answers 
(
    question_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES questions(user_id)
                        PRIMARY KEY 
                        CHECK (user_id>0), 
    answer TEXT NOT NULL      -- answer must have text
);

CREATE TABLE questions 
(
    user_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY 
                    REFERENCES user_info(user_id) 
                    PRIMARY KEY 
                    CHECK (user_id>0), 
    question_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tags(question_id) 
                        NOT NULL 
                        CHECK (user_id>0)
                        SERIAL, 
    body TEXT NOT NULL,                    -- question must have body 
    title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,            -- no empty title
    moderator_removal BOOLEAN NOT NULL,    -- by default false
    sent_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tags 
(
    question_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES questions(question_id) 
                        CHECK (user_id>0), 
    tag VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT no_duplicate_tag UNIQUE (question_id,tag)
)


CREATE TABLE user_infos 
(
    user_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES questions(user_id) 
                    PRIMARY KEY 
                    CHECK (user_id>0)
                    SERIAL
                    UNIQUE, 
    username VARCHAR(25),
    email VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL       -- maximun possible
                       UNIQUE,
    password_sha512 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    is_moderator BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    is_Login BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    has_been_sent_a_moderator_message BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);



-- to have default values

ALTER TABLE questions ALTER COLUMN moderator_removal SET DEFAULT FALSE

ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN is_moderator SET DEFAULT FALSE
ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN is_login SET DEFAULT FALSE
ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN has_been_sent_a_moderator_message SET DEFAULT FALSE


-- to have default values

ALTER TABLE questions ALTER COLUMN moderator_removal SET DEFAULT FALSE

ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN is_moderator SET DEFAULT FALSE
ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN is_login SET DEFAULT FALSE
ALTER TABLE user_info ALTER COLUMN has_been_sent_a_moderator_message SET DEFAULT FALSE
```

**Relational Table**

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db777.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/db/db777.png)

**What would you improve in the DDL queries?**

Comment: You didn't post any queries... only DDL.

Comment: @Pukku: I have had the idea that DDL is a subset of SQL.

Comment: (OT) As a first step remove or replace the dashes (with underscores for example) in the indentifiers. Or quote them.

Comment: @Milen: I did that. I also changed a few varchars to nvarchars.

Comment: There's no "nvarchar" type in Postgres.

Comment: @Milen: Thank you for pointing that out! - Do you know which databases support `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use varchar(4000) and so, is 4000 actually a conceptual maximum of how long the string can be there? Or did you just pick something "big enough for everything"? If the second, just use the *text* datatype. It will be just as fast (actually, a tiny bit faster, but you will not likely be able to measure that).

sent_time looks like it should be a *timestamptz*. Don't store date/time in a varchar.

auto_increment is not in postgres, use a *serial* column.

You have a circular reference between Tags and Questions, which I'm sure you didn't intend. And your check constraint on Questions.question_id appears checks user_id - too much copy/paste I bet.

Finally, don't use mixed case identifiers. Do everything lowercase, so you don't have to quote them. For instance, use lowercase for column and table names.

Comment: *Finally, don't use mixed case identifiers. Do everything lowercase, so you don't have to quote them.* --- Do you mean I should change the commands such as `CREATE TABLE`, `USER_ID` and `NOT NULL` to lowercase?

Comment: The following thread is based on your last paragraph: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199868/to-understand-a-sentence-about-the-case-in-sql-ddl-queries

Comment: @Magnus: In which systems do you need *to quote [column and table names]* when you use Uppercase?

Comment: I removed the primary key form tags(question_id). - Ken says that if you use the primary key in the table too. It allows one question have only one tag at the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196873/to-prevent-the-use-of-duplicate-tags-in-a-database/1196996#1196996

Comment: No need to lowercase the CREATE TABLE and NOT NULL parts. But lowercase USER_ID. My experience is that most databases need quoting in cases like this, and the rules for how they fold things are different if you don't quote it. Sticking to just lowercase (or just uppercase - that's mainly a matter of preference) and then never quoting them is a good way to just escape having to deal with it.