# Is there any ISO standard of how to write SQL queries in DDL?

Tags: sql, database, ddl

I am doing my first database project.

I would like to know which of the following ways should I use to make SQL queries in DDL.

### #1

```
CREATE TABLE employees (   
    id            INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name    CHAR(50)  NULL,
    last_name     CHAR(75)  NOT NULL,
    dateofbirth   DATE      NULL
);
```

### #2

```
CREATE TABLE employees (   
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name CHAR(50) NULL,
    last_name CHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    dateofbirth DATE NULL
);
```

### #3

```
CREATE TABLE employees (   
    ID            integer   PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME    char(50)  NULL,
    LAST_NAME     char(75)  NOT NULL,
    DATAOFBIRTH   data      NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter to the database, and so you should generally go for what's more readable and maintainable.  There are a lot of different conventions out there, and I switch between them depending on circumstances all the time.  Imo, what's good for a small query isn't the same as what's good for a more-complicated query.

In this case, I think your #3 looks most readable.  But that's just my opinion and if there are conventions or existing expectations for how the code looks where you are, stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

[Sql coding Convections suggest](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/sql_best_practices_p1.aspx) :

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(   
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
first_name CHAR(50) NULL,
last_name CHAR(75) NOT NULL,
dateofbirth DATE NULL
);
```